# How to inject a third party library to an angular.js service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am having trouble while trying to load the angular-cache library to my service. I used bower to add angular-cache to my project and it is successfully added. When I debug the service code on Chrome I see in the "Networks" tab that angular-cache is loaded:

```
Name: angular-cache.js
Method: GET
Status: 200
Type: script
Initiator: require.js:1901
Size: 6,5 kb
Time: 16 ms
```

There is a config.js file that I load all my libraries. This line is for angular-cache:

```
'angular-cache': '../bower_components/angular-cache/dist/angular-cache',
```

and this is the line inside shim:

```
'angular-cache': ['angular'],
```

And this is the service:

```
 define(
    [ 'angular', 'services-module'],
    function(angular, services) {
        services.factory(
          'MyService',
           [
            "$location",
            "$interval",
            "MyOtherService",
            "CacheFactory",
            function($location, $interval, otherService, cacheFactory) {

               var service = {
                    myCachingFunction : function(parameters){

                    }, 
                    getCache : function(cacheId) {

                    }
                }
                return service;
            } ]);
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CacheFactoryProvider
```

[This](http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/) is the github page of the angular-cache. What am I missing?

Comment: Is CacheFactoryProvider the right casing? Providers are case sensitive.

Comment: @WesleySkeen In angular-cache documentation they use it like that.

Comment: I believe that in addition to what Ioana Cucuruzan writes in her answer, you should also shim the `angular-cache` to depend on Angular, so that they are loaded in the correct order. If that doesn't work, you should probably add more details of your configuration in the question. You may also want to take a look at [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I updated my post with the line of shim. Although I am not sure I did it correctly

Comment: I believe the shim should be like: `'angular-cache': { deps: ['angular'] },...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this, I guess that this is your service.js:

```
define(
['angular', 'services-module'],
function(angular, services) {
    services.factory(
      'MyService',
       [
        "$location",
        "$interval",
        "MyOtherService",
        "CacheFactory",
        function($location, $interval, otherService, cacheFactory) {
```

In your app.js:

```
define(
['angular', 'angular-cache'],
function(angular) {
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngResource', 'app.controllers', 'app.directives', 'app.services', 'app.filters', 'app.routes', 'app.interceptors', 'angular-cache' ]);
```

In config.js:

```
    shim: {
      'angular-cache': {
         deps: ['angular']
       }
    }
```

I'm guessing that you are using Require with Angular.

Comment: Yes. But this is not working: Unknown provider: angular-cacheProvider

Comment: This is yours service, but where is your app?

Something like this:
angular.module('', [])

You need to load module:
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-cache'])

And use my code above. I have update the code

Comment: I have this line in another file called app.js: var myApp= angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngResource', 'app.controllers', 'app.directives', 'app.services', 'app.filters', 'app.routes',
   'app.interceptors' ]);

Comment: You need to tell you application to use that module. In your app.js:  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngResource', 'app.controllers', 'app.directives', 'app.services', 'app.filters', 'app.routes', 'app.interceptors', 'angular-cache' ]);

Answer (score 0):

You want to include is as a module like this:

```
define(
    [ 'angular', 'services-module', 'angular-cache'],
    function(angular, services, cache) {
...
```